# Does anyone know what this error code means? my program worked fine yesterday. "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 91.0.4472
Get LATEST driver version for 91.0.4472
UNEXPECTED ERROR:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_91.0.4472 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Comment: That usually means you are behind a corporate firewall that is doing HTTPS proxy, and is supplying their own self-signed certificate.  You may need to add the corporate certificate to your trusted store.

Answer (score 0):

SSL verification errors can happen due to a number of reasons. Some of them are:

- General network issues or outages
- A real SSL issue, it is damaged or simply it has expired.
- A new firewall rule that could be blocking your network traffic.
- An antivirus software
- A network security client ot network tool
- A Python version/system libraries with SSL issues (2.7.11 seems to work for most users).

Verify you are not having any network or communication issues or changees; or new software that have installed on your computer.
Can you try again after upgrading to the latest version of Google Cloud SDK, and Python 2.7.11 and verify that none of these are the cause?

There are some procedures like [this](https://sectigostore.com/page/what-is-an-ssl-certificate_verify_failed-error-and-how-do-i-resolve-it/) one or [this](https://moreless.medium.com/how-to-fix-python-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-97772d9dd14c) one to try fo fix your issue.